# Eclipse console no output

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, jvm, java

I am using Eclipse Juno under Ubuntu 12.04. I have installed CDT and the console works perfectly there. I had some problems compiling some java code from command line - it was related to the fact that there were multiple jdks installed and the system compiled with 1.7 and tried to run with 1.6 -> int produced some error. After I've set the JAVA_HOME to 1.7 and java-alternatives based on this : https://askubuntu.com/questions/121654/how-to-set-default-java-version everything worked out. I haven't noticed until now, that probably this affected Eclipse, since when now I try to run something it doesn't show up in the console, but if I run the binaries from the bin directory directly from the terminal the output is shown in the terminal. After java -version I get the following response:

```
java version "1.7.0_09"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.3.3) (7u9-2.3.3-0ubuntu1~12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)
```

How can I make Eclipse show up the results of the run in the console?

Comment: I am voting to close this question as **Not Reproducible or Caused by a Typo** based on the self answer by the author of this question, which states "*I installed Aptana3 and it changed the color scheme of eclipse and when I tried to fix it I changed a lot of colors and by mistake I changed the background and the output color both to white, so actually the output was there, just I was not able to see it*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed Aptana3 and it changed the color scheme of eclipse and when I tried to fix it I changed a lot of colors and by mistake I changed the background and the output color both to white, so actually the output was there, just I was not able to see it.

Answer (score 1):

You should check in you project properties, which version of Java is set on the build path.
Right click on your project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries.

Also see if the Console view is active.

Comment: I have a lot of versions of jres, I tried some of them, but no success. Which one should I choose? I have CDC1.x,j2se1.x,MSGi/Min1.x and JRE1.1 . It does not work if I set it to the workspace default either.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on your project. Select "Properties".
Select the "Run/Debug Settings" Property on the left of the new window.

In the right window, click on your executable to highlight (ie - Test.exe) and click "Edit".
In the Environment tab, hit "New"
Name: PATH 
Value: Path to your MinGW bin directory. (For me this was: C:\devcore\MinGW\bin)

Click "OK" on all windows to close down.

Try running again, it should print output to the screen.